# sharing code from a browserify file

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, browserify

I have a JavaScript library that is using Browserify to keep the code modular.

The library itself uses basic Browserify functionality to require other JS files.

**myLibrary.js**

```
var utils = require('helpers/utils.js')
console.log("Hello, I am logging from myLibrary")
function my_api(){
  utils.someFn()
}
```

I'm using Gulp to browserify myLibrary.js and it is being built correctly, I've put several logs into myLibrary.js and when I load the file in an example html file I can see the logs.

I have an example index.html file that uses myLibrary.js and I expect my_api to be accessible from index.html.

**index.html**

```
<script src="my_url/myLibrary.js"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>
```

**app.js**

```
my_api()
```

**Chrome console**

```
Hello I am logging from myLibrary (myLibrary.js)
Uncaught ReferenceError: my_api is not defined (app.js)
```

I've tried to defer the loading of app.js until myLibrary.js was ready but I'm beginning that that is not the problem.

Comment: Your browserify output might be encapsulating all your code. Not super versed with Browserify, but try returning my_api or ```module.exports = my_api```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to export your public functions.

```
module.exports = {my_api: my_api};
```

Comment: I want to be able to use the functions inside myLibrary by loading it through an html file <script src="my_url/myLibrary.js">.

I would have to use Browserify where ever I use this file if I were to do that. Is what I'm trying to achieve not possible with Browserify?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. The file, as you have it, does not expose `my_api` outside the scope of the module.

Comment: I want myLibrary to have my_api exposed so that I can load myLibrary.js into any html file using script tags and call my_api.

I want to use Browserify so that any I can break up myLibrary into multiple js files. 

What I'm asking is whether or not it is possible to expose functions from a file built using Browserify (myLibrary.js) to a project that is not using Browserify (index.html/app.js)

As an example: If you were to use myLibrary.js in your project then I would much rather have you load it using script tags than force you to require it using Browserify.

Comment: You're trying to use a JS file written with the commonJS format. You can only use that in a browser using something like Browserify. @Ephapox.

Comment: I don't agree with your suggestion that a consumer should not have to use Browserify. You absolutely should __not__ be polluting the global namespace with your functions!

Answer (score 0):

The solution I ended up using was to expose one global object that contains all the methods I want to expose through myLibrary using the window object.

myLibrary.js is requiring a utility function file and using them as helpers in the methods that I want to expose.

**myLibrary.js**

```
var util = require("utils.js")
window.myGlobalObjWithAUniqueName = {
  myFn: function(){
    util.someHelper()
  }
}
```

Then I use Browserify to create the new browserified_myLibrary.js and use its methods in any file I want to load it in.

**index.html**

```
<script src="browserified_myLibrary.js"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>
```

**app.js**

```
myGlobalObjWithAUniqueName.myFn()
```

Not sure if this is the best way of doing this but this seems to suit my need to modularize a client side library and use it without having to use Browserify every time I use it.

Answer (score 0):

You may also want to look into the `--standalone` option exposed by browserify:

> When opts.standalone is a non-empty string, a standalone module is created with that name and a umd wrapper. You can use namespaces in the standalone global export using a . in the string name as a separator, for example 'A.B.C'. The global export will be sanitized and camel cased.

From https://github.com/substack/node-browserify#usage